# ADODB.Command.Execute not working with parameter

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a function in VBA to handle my SQL procedure calls. I've run into a problem where if the code needs to supply a parameter to the procedure it is not working. The code is below, it works fine if I call the procedure without the optional argument. I've added a breakpoint before the execute; the if statement triggers fine and the immediate window tells me that `?cmd.Parameters(0)` and `?cmd.Parameters(1)`   have values yet I get the error: myprocedure expects parameter '@sd_name' which was not supplied. The procedure only expects 2 arguments and I don't even care about the name, they can just be passed by position.

```
Function RunSQL(comtext As String, Optional Params As String = "No") As ADODB.Recordset

Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim recset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

TryConnect

cmd.commandtext = comtext
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = GlobalCon
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

If Params <> "No" Then
    Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@sd_name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm
    cmd.Parameters("@sd_name").Value = Params
    Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@year_wk_num", adInteger, adParamInput, 100)
    cmd.Parameters.Append prm
    cmd.Parameters("@year_wk_num").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Control Sheet").Range("year_wk").Value
End If
--------------!Error Here----------------
Set recset = cmd.Execute
Set RunSQL = recset

Set cmd = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you should probably make that optional parameter a `Boolean` defaulting to `False`.

Comment: What's the command string like? AFAIK ADODB parameters should be *positional* and thus it seems weird that the error message asks for named params. Try removing the `@` in the parameter names. If that fails, replace the parameters with `?` question marks in the command text, and add/append the parameters in the order they appear in the query. Also I would declare a separate `ADODB.Parameter` variable for each parameter, and `Append` them last, *after* setting their value.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I was trying to pass them as positional originally, they actually had different names in the vba and i changed them to match the sp parameter name to see if that fixed the issue. Also the parameters are in the order of the procedure already. I will try separate parameters and setting value first and let you know

Comment: Are parameters optional in stored procedure? If not, it will fail if you do not supply them. Please show snippet of stored procedure.

Comment: @Parfait, Parameters are not optional in stored procedure but are being supplied in as far as command.parameter(0) and command.parameter(1) in VBA show. Both have a valid value, that's the problem, not sure why it's telling me it isn't being supplied

Comment: Forgive me, but can we see this stored proc to both reproduce your issue and verify ourselves? Right now, we can only take your word for it. And did you remove `@` per @Mat'sMug's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, simple mistake, seems you cannot add parameters in this way to `ADODB.Command.CommandType adCmdText` rather it must be `adCmdStoredProc`. I guess you can probably add them as part of the `commandtext` string if you wish to use that type as [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee266308(v=bts.10).aspx) is saying it can be used as a textual definition of a stored procedure. However in this case I've just done the below and it's working fine (Still needs to be `adCmdText` when no parameters are required and calling VBA defined query string rather than procedure):

```
If Params <> "No" Then
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 'added this line
```